# Go West! A Lucky Luke Adventure : crash at startup

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, go-west-a-lucky-luke-adventure

I found out this old game in the attic. I tried to run it on Windows 10, but it crashed at startup. What could be the problem ?

This is what I've tried:

- Installed DirectPlay
- Run as administrator
- Test out in virtual machines that the game works on Windows XP and Windows XP x64

With some reverse engineering, I've listed the .dll files this program loads:

```
kernel32.dll
user32.dll
advapi32.dll
msvcp80.dll
opengl32.dll
glu32.dll
glut32.dll
dsound.dll
msvcr80.dll
comctl32.dll
hid.dll
setupapi.dll
avifil32.dll
ws2_32.dll
gdi32.dll
luckyluke.dll
```

@Mixxiphoid Thanks to the dependencywalker.com tool, I listed the missing ddl's :

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPINIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ATOMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COMM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L2-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L3-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LARGEINTEGER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-OBSOLETE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MARSHAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMESPACE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NORMALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PCW-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSSNAPSHOT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-ANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-KEY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRYUSERSPECIFIC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHLWAPI-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHLWAPI-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRINGANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSTEMTOPOLOGY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSTEMTOPOLOGY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-URL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-XSTATE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-XSTATE-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-CONFIG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-KERNEL32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CLASSICPROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONTROLLER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-UAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-TIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-SETTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-APPCONTAINER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-WINSVC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELLCOM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-STATESEPARATION-HELPERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-IDENTITY-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-7.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-STATE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-UNLOCK-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-BASE-UTIL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CONTAINERS-CMCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CONTAINERS-CMCLIENT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CALENDAR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-MIDLPROXYSTUB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-PRIVATE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-PRIVATE-L1-3-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-MINIDUMP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FEATURESTAGING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALREGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-5.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-APP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSM-APPNOTIFY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-ANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TEXTINPUT-CLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TEXTINPUT-CLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-TOOLHELP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSIONANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSIONANSI-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERRORPRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-PROPERTYSETPRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-PROPERTYSETPRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REGISTRATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-COREUI-SECRUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-ADVAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-ADVAPI32-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-KERNEL32-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-NORMALIZ-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-OLE32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHELL32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-USER32-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-VERSION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DWMAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-TDH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTLOG-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-GDI-DPIINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-HTTP-TIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MISC-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-MM-MISC-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-INTERFACECONTEXTS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NTUSER-RECTANGLE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-OLE32-IE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-OOBE-NOTIFICATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RO-TYPERESOLUTION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-CLIPBOARD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-7.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-9.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SHELL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINEVENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WMPOINTER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACCESSHLPR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPABILITY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTOAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ISOLATEDCONTAINER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ISOLATIONPOLICY-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LOGON-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LOGON-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-ANSI-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSAPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDLPARSECOND-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SYSTEMFUNCTIONS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-COMHELPERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-STREAM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-STREAM-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-TASKPOOL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-THREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-UNICODEANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-ASSOCIATIONS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-CHANGENOTIFY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-NAMESPACE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHDIRECTORY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELLFOLDERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHLWAPI-IE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHLWAPI-WINRT-STORAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-STORAGE-EXPORTS-EXTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-STORAGE-EXPORTS-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-MF-PAL-L2-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPDEFAULTS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-CACHE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-CACHE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-INTERNAL-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-INTERNAL-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-INTERNAL-L1-1-4.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-DCOMP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-HLINK-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-ORIENTATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-SERVICE-DEVICEDIRECTORY-CLAIMS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-SHELLCHROMEAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADSI-ACTIVEDS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-HWPROF-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-LSA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-MSI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NPUSERNAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NTMARTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-PSM-APP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-SAFER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPCOMPAT-AEINV-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPCOMPAT-AEPIC-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPCOMPAT-APPHELP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DAXCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DEPLOYMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RESTRICTEDAPPCONTAINER-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-STATE-EXT-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-USERCONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-VIEWSCALEFACTOR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOYONECORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUDIOCORE-PAL-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUDIOCORE-SPATIAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-CONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-BIOMETRICS-WINBIO-CORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-APARTMENTRESTRICTION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-CLBCATQ-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-COML2-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-4.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-OLE32-L1-1-5.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-PSMREGISTER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-SUSPENDRESILIENCY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CONTAINERS-POLICYMANAGERCLI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CORE-PKEYHELPER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CORE-RESOURCEPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DESKTOPAPPX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DESKTOPAPPX-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-DM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-DM-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-DM-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DEVMGMT-POLICY-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DIRECT2D-DESKTOP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DOMAINJOIN-NETJOIN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DRIVER-SETUP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DWMAPI-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DWMAPIDXGI-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DWMAPIDXGI-EXT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-DXCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-D3DKMT-GDI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DX-DDRAW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DXCORE-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-DXCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EDPUTIL-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EDPUTIL-POLICY-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ELS-ELSCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EVENTING-RUNDOWN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FAMILYSAFETY-CHILDACCOUNT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FIREWALLAPI-WEBPROXY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FVEAPI-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-CLIPPING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-CREATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DEVCAPS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-GDIPLUS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRINT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-RENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-WCS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GPAPI-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GUI-DUI70-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-IMM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-DATETIME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-CURRENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-PACKAGE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNELBASE-PROCESSTHREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNELBASE-PROCESSTHREAD-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MININPUT-INPUTHOST-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MININPUT-INPUTHOST-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MM-MSACM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MM-PEHELPER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MPR-MULTIPLEPROVIDERROUTER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MRMCORER-RESMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-WCMAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-WLANAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-WLANSTORAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DC-ACCESS-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DIALOGBOX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DRAW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DRAW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-DRAW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-GUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-KEYBOARD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MENU-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-5-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MISC-L1-5-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MOUSE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-3-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-3-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-3-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-RECTANGLE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-ROTATIONMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SERVER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-4.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOWCLASS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOWSTATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ODBC-ODBC32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-BINDCTX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-IE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLE32-OLEAUTOMATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OLEACC-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-OOBE-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PRINTER-PRNTVPT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-EXTENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-USERENV-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-USERENV-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RAS-RASAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RAS-TAPI32-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RDR-DAVHLPR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-REINFO-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RESOURCEMANAGER-CRM-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RESOURCES-DEPLOYMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RESOURCES-LANGUAGEOVERLAY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RESOURCES-LANGUAGEOVERLAY-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RO-TYPERESOLUTION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RPC-SSL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-DEVCAPS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-OBJECT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-RGN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-GDI-RGN-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-INPUT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-PRIVATE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-MINUSER-PRIVATE-EXT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-CURSOR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DC-ACCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DPI-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-DPI-L1-2-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-IAM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-INTEGRATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-RAWINPUT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYNCH-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSCOLORS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-EXT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECUR32-TRANSLATENAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUTHZ-HELPER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPAUTHZ-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPAUTHZ-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CHAMBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDUI-INTERNAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDUI-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CRYPTUI-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFSWRT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFSWRT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-NGC-LOCAL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SLC-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-WINSCARD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-WINSCARD-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-USERMGR-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-USERTOKEN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-WINSTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION-WTSAPI32-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SETUPAPI-CLASSINSTALLERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SETUPAPI-CLASSINSTALLERS-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SETUPAPI-INF-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SETUPAPI-INF-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-DIRECTORY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-EMBEDDEDMODE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-FILEPLACEHOLDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHELL32-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL32-SHELLCOM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL32-SHELLFOLDERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SMBSHARE-BROWSERCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-STORAGE-SENSE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-STORAGE-SENSE-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SXS-OLEAUTOMATION-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-TSF-MSCTF-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-TSF-MSCTF-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-UI-VIEWMANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-USP10-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-UI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WER-XBOX-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WEVTAPI-EVENTLOG-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-DEVICE-ACCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-STORAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WLAN-ONEXUI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WLAN-SCARD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WPC-WEBFILTER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WWAN-WWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WWAN-WWAPI-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN32-SUBSYSTEM-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WINDOWSCORE-DEVICEINFO-L1-1-0.DLL
HVSIFILETRUST.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
MSS32.DLL
```

Comment: Do you know what was the last OS it worked on?

Comment: Are all the DLL's loaded by the program located in the same folder where the executable is?

Comment: Did you use https://www.dependencywalker.com/ to check the requirements?

Comment: Exception 0xc0000005 is an access violation. It means the game is trying to access parts in the computers memory without being authorised. It's a common problem with old software on new computers. You mention successfully running the game in a virtual box running XP; have you tried running the game in *compatibility mode* for Windows XP?

Comment: @Gnemlock I tested with compatibility mode and it didn't work

Comment: @Phoenix Windows XP (32 and 64 bits)

Comment: @Mixxiphoid didn't know about your tool : I will give a try and upload the report

Comment: @Mixxiphoid It seems that a lot of forwarded dependency couldn't be found : API-MS-WIN-*.ddl, EXT-MS-ONECORE-*.ddl, EXT-MS-WIN-*.ddl, HVSIFILETRUST.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL and MSS32.DLL : any idea what I should install to get them ?

Comment: @jy95 note that you do not necessarily need all the reported DLL's. But most can be found here: https://www.dll-files.com/